# Accessing table values on code.org app lab

Tags: javascript, datatable, code.org

I made a table on https://studio.code.org/p/applab using the Data Browser. All of the row and column names are integers. How would I access the text inside a cell in the table?

For arrays, I simply use console.log(array[n-1]); to display the nth element of the array. Is there a similar command for tables? I named my table table, but console.log(table[5,6]); doesn't retrieve the text found in the 6th row and 7th column; it returns an error saying "Unknown identifier: table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in App Lab entered in the Data Browser can be accessed from code using the `readRecords` block. Columns in data tables are accessed by column name, not by index. For example, if you named your columns `column1` and `column2`, you could print the data in row `3`, `column2` with:

```
function readTable(tableName, rowId, columnName, callback) {
  readRecords(tableName, {}, function(records) {
    for (var i =0; i < records.length; i++) {
      var record = records[i];
      if (record.id === rowId) {
        callback(record[columnName]);
        return;
      }
    }
    console.log('could not find row ' + rowId + ' column ' + columnName + ' in table ' + tableName);
  });
}

readTable('mytable', 3, 'column2', function(value) {
  console.log('value: ' + value);
})
```

Other resources:

- overview of data storage in App Lab: https://code.org/applab/docs/tabledatastorage
- puzzle progressions guiding you through data storage: https://studio.code.org/s/csppostap/

Comment: I tried to create a function to do this in general for column x, row y by substituting x and y for column2 and 3 respectively in your answer. However, it gives an error because it treats the column name as a variable. If I put quotations around the input to treat it as a string then it prints undefined. Is there a workaround to create a function to do the process in general?

Comment: To access a column name as a variable you would have to do `record[columnName]`, not `record.columnName`. I've updated the example code to be more general.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. Do you know why Javascript treats tables and arrays so differently, if arrays are just a special case of tables (specifically, 1 row tables)? Accessing row n, column k of a table should be as simple as accessing the nth row of an array. (If this can't be answered here I'll just post it as a separate question)

Comment: Arrays are javascript, but tables are specific to Code.org and not part of the core javascript language. A table contains an array of records with named fields, which is convenient for reading a record, modifying it, and writing it back to storage, or possibly deleting it, but is less convenient when you want to treat a table as an array of arrays. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Displayname if I've answered the programming part of your question, could you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks!